# Fixed Block Position CSS Problems

Tags: blocks, theming

Hello i was using the floating Block module to keep my right hand main menu in a fixed position as a person scrolls down the page. Then i deceided that maybe its overkill just for one menu and i have tried it with css.

```
#sidebar-left {
 position: fixed;
    top: 0
float:right;
  right:20px;
  width:110px;
}
```

My theme is fixed width but im getting differant results when viewed in differant screen resolutions.  I was wanting the block to just appear to the right of the the 2nd right hand block (with the logo). Try as i might though im struggling to achieve it.

You can view my site (and the right hand menu) here-
http://onlinebanter.com/welcome

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ive sorted it with

margin-left: 845px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 110px;

Thanks